# inserting of data not happening in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am new to plsql.I have a table where i need to insert the data(some dummy data).So,i thought to use plsql block and using `For loop` it will insert the data automatically.The plsql block is runned successfully,but the data are stored as empty.The block I tried is:

```
declare
v_number1 number;
v_number2 number;
v_number3 number;
begin
For Lcntr IN 2..17
LOOP
v_number1 := v_number1+1;
v_number2 := v_number2+2;
v_number3 := v_number3+3;
  Insert into stu.result(res_id,stu_id,eng,maths,science) values (stu.seq_no.NEXTVAL,Lcntr,v_number1,v_number2,v_number3);
END LOOP;
end;
```

But my table is loaded as:(please ignore first two row data,i inserted it manually):

[image]

The data for eng,maths,science is not being inserted.why it is happening so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your variables are `NULL`. `NULL + 1 = NULL` as well.

If you modify declaration to

```
v_number1 number := 0;
v_number2 number := 0;
v_number3 number := 0;
```

something might happen.